# DELL U2515H-display and Mac Mini (Late 2011)

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt, hdmi

We're trying to get a DELL U2515H (2560 x 1440) running on a Mac Mini (late 2011). Currently it's connected with HDMI.

Unfortunately it seems like resolutions only up to 1920 x 1200 are supported using HDMI on the mac mini:
*HDMI port with support for up to 1920-by-1200 resolution*
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp632?locale=en_US

However, resolutions up to 2560x1600 are supported using Thunderbolt:
*Thunderbolt port with support for up to 2560-by-1600 resolution*
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp632?locale=en_US

So the question is: 
which cable should we get to get to connect the Display -> Thunderbolt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thunderbolt is a "multi-plexing" of multiple signals

- PCIe
- USB
- DisplayPort

If all you are connecting is a monitor, a simple DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable will work fine.  Since the Mac mini has mDP and the Dell has both mDP and DP, either a mDP-mDP or mDP-DP will function.

Comment: Thanks. This one should do the trick then? (The text is in Swedish but I'm sure you'll figure it out):
https://www.kjell.com/se/sortiment/dator-natverk/kablar-adaptrar/displayport/mini-displayport-kablar/anslutningskabel-mini-displayport-2-m-p98686

Comment: That looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a Thunderbolt cable to attach the Mac Mini Thunderbolt port to the Dell Mini DisplayPort.

Comment: Would this cable work? (Swedish text, sorry, but I think you'll figure it out):
https://www.kjell.com/se/sortiment/dator-natverk/kablar-adaptrar/displayport/mini-displayport-kablar/anslutningskabel-mini-displayport-2-m-p98686